# How to change orientation using a menu button?

Tags: java, android

I would like to handle the orientation change of my app with a menu button, so it doesn't change views when the device is turned, but when the user presses a menu item. Can you tell me the best way to do this? Everything that comes to my mind seems to be stupid.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [setRequestedOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) so specify an orientation.
In your xml-Manifest file you can specify a `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to not change the orientation automatically.

Comment: Hm, it seems that this does not use my landscape layout-xml file. it just turns the normal layout around. how can i change this?

Comment: @TheBrillowable - Override `onConfigurationChanged()`, and re-call `setContentView()` in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```